# How can I complete the weekly Genius Invokation TCG challenges?

Tags: genshin-impact

The battlepass now has a weekly quest to beat two TCG challenges.

[image: Complete Invokation TCG Weekly Guest Challenges 2 times]

I am unsure how I might complete these. I tried inviting Mona to the Cat's Tail for a match but that did not count towards this weekly quest.

How do I complete this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have progressed far enough through the card tutorial, the weekly guests will start to show up in the Cat's Tail. They will be sitting at the tables, and have a playing card icon over their heads. Simply challenge them to get the battle pass reward. If you check your TCG Player's Manual, it will show who the current weekly challenges are.

As you can see here, looking in the Guest Challenge tab my weekly challengers are Lan, Ellin, Mao and Barbara. I have yet to fight Lan:

[image]

And in the Cat's Tail, I can find Lan waiting to fight me:

[image]

Sometimes the challenger in the manual will have a time under their name, indicating they have not yet arrived at the Cat's Tail (so you can't challenge them yet):

[image]